# Selecting appropriate priors for bayglm with binomial distribution

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, uninformative-prior

I've been running a `glm` with a binomial distribution and two predictors which are date and a categorical variable named 'pond':

```
glm(yes/no ~ date + pond, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=dat)
```

However, running into trouble as 'pond has 15 levels (leading to quasi separation). Would running a `bayglm` be appropriate to deal with this issue (I can't reduce the number of levels)? If so, how would I select appropriate priors, given that I don't have any prior/expert data. Are there certain 'default' priors I should use, considering it's a binomial glm?

Comment: I am voting to leave open because the questions seem to be "Is the method I mention here appropriate?" and "How should I choose a prior in the absence of data/expert judgement?". These sound like conceptual questions, not programming ones.

Comment: An alternative could be regularization. If by `bayglm` you mean this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arm/versions/1.10-1/topics/bayesglm then that function already does a choice of prior. See http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/priors11.pdf